# SQL statement to look at ALL the previous rows

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I have the following table

```
create table interest_earning_assets (
  key integer
  month_of varchar(7),
  principal_distribution numeric(38,2),
  closed_loan_amount numeric(38,2)
);
```

Data looks like this

```
key month_of    principal_distribution  closed_loan_amount
24  2017-01     4133500.00              5984695.00
23  2016-12     12018303.93             26941275.40
22  2016-11     6043945.46              21239620.20
21  2016-10     2864195.39              20368518.20
```

I have two requirements.

1. Sum up `closed_amount_values`

For each month (currently 24 months, next month 25 months, then 26 etc), I need to sum up `closed_amount_values` with the values of *all* the previous months i.e

```
2017-01 sum(closed_loan_amount for 2016-10 + 2016-11 + 2016-12 + 2017-01)
2016-12 sum(closed_loan_amount for 2016-10 + 2016-11 + 2016-12)
2016-11 sum(closed_loan_amount for 2016-10 + 2016-11) 
2016-10 sum(closed_loan_amount for 2016-10 )
```

2. Subtract the sum of `closed_loan_amount` to principal_distribution

Once I have the summed up values, I need to subtract the sum of `closed_loan_amount` to principal_distribution for each month

```
2017-01 principal_distribution for 2017-01 - sum(closed_loan_amount for 2016-10 + 2016-11 + 2016-12 + 2017-01)
2016-12 principal_distribution for 2016-12 - sum(closed_loan_amount for 2016-10 + 2016-11 + 2016-12)
2016-11 principal_distribution for 2016-11 - sum(closed_loan_amount for 2016-10 + 2016-11) 
2016-10 principal_distribution for 2016-10 - sum(closed_loan_amount for 2016-10 )
```

Redshift does not support Stored procedures and I am not proficient in Python. So I am attempted to use lag thusly

```
select month_of, closed_loan_amount, 
       lag(closed_loan_amount,1) over (order by month_of desc) as previous_month 
from public.interest_earning_assets
```

It works but only gives me the previous month value. I am also looking into using CTEs but I just got this assignment today. How can I do that in SQL?

Comment: `sum(closed_loan_amount) over (order by month-of rows between unbounded preceding and current row)` I have no idea how much Redshift supports those operations though. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_Window_function_synopsis.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `sum` window function with a window specification to look at all the previous rows to get the sum of closed_loan_amount and subtract it from principal_distribution.

```
select month_of, closed_loan_amount, 
 principal_distribution
-sum(closed_loan_amount) over (order by month_of desc rows between current row and unbounded following) as some_value
from public.interest_earning_assets
```

Comment: I need to learn about Windowing functions like this. I didn't know I could do this. Thank you. Accepted and voted up. Thank you!!!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT [key], month_of,
       SUM(closed_loan_amount) OVER(ORDER BY month_of),
       principal_distribution + SUM(closed_loan_amount) OVER(ORDER BY month_of)
FROM interest_earning_assets
```

Windowed version of `SUM` with an `ORDER BY` clause calculates the running total of a field according to an order defined by a second field that appears in the `ORDER BY` clause.